# Redgate Source Control Tool Need to have ANSI encoding after sync with database

Tags: encoding, utf-8, redgate

We Need to have ANSI encoded file for database objects in target repository after sync with the database through source control for oracle.
Currently we get UTF-8 encoded files in repository.
We have made changes in config files (.xml files)in all folders by setting encoding parameter to ANSI, still we receive UTF-8 files.

How can we get ANSI encoded files in target repositories after syncing up from source control redgate tool.

Comment: Same question for me